# Use of article after 'my career as'

Tags: grammar, articles

Which article should be used after 'my career as'? 
I mainly find an indefinite article (my career as a software developer, my career as a neurologist, etc.), but is it correct to say:

> My career as (the) editor-in-chief ended after the attack.

or

> He started his career as (the) chief nurse in the local hospital.

(As there is only 1 editor-in-chief or chief nurse?)

Comment: You seem to understand it correctly. It depends on what you want to say. One is more general than the other.

Comment: I'd use the null article in the first example, especially as prior reference is virtually demanded. But 'chief nurse' is not as well-known a title, if it is indeed a title, so I'd stick with the less definite 'the'. (The null article is invisible, just like the zero article. You can look them up on ELU. Google either, or 'Masters'.)

Comment: It’s not that simple, even differentiating “editor-in-chief” and mere “editor”. No-one had a career as “editor-in-chief”, nor “started as (a/the) chief nurse…” Both worked their way up.

“My career as (the) editor-in-chief…” seems correct, article or none. Might dropping “… ended after the attack” make it more clear?

 “My time as editor-in-chief…”

 “My spell as an editor-in-chief…”

 “My work as the editor-in-chief…”; all are better.

I don’t think the idea was to argue about this aspect, yet article or none “My career ended as (an/the) editor-in-chief…” is more correct.

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly identified the distinction at the end of the question. It's essentially the same as choosing whether to use 'a' or 'the' in general; the 'the' cases you cite both refer to a specific singular role, whereas the first few are one of many interchangeable role-holders.

It's worth noting it isn't strictly broken down by job title. We can refer to "my career as the chief nurse" (at Example Hospital), but it's just as grammatically valid to say "my career as a chief nurse" if we're referring to a series of chief nurse roles in different hospitals.